# how to parse and change values in sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

I have sqlite db(around 10k entries)  with time stored in following format: `hh:mmam/pm` for example `12:40pm`, `6:50am` and I need it in milliseconds so they can be compared. Is there a way to make it happen? I am working with Java.

EDIT: Sorry, my question is ambiguous. I want to take value, transform it to milliseconds and overwrite it back, so all values will be stored in milliseconds rather than current format.

Comment: What language are you using with your SQLlite?

Comment: Totally forgot, I am using java

Comment: What is the type of the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved with the following python code, post it just in case anyone else will need to do something similar. After prog is done had to manually change type of the column from TEXT to NUMERIC

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

def unix_time(dt):
    """Takes datetime object and returns its unix time since epoch"""
    epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)  #January 1st 1970
    delta = dt - epoch
    return delta.total_seconds()

def unix_time_millis(dt):
    return unix_time(dt) * 1000 #milliseconds

db = sqlite3.connect("your_db.sqlite")#connect to initial database
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from fancy_table")
all_entries = cursor.fetchall() #get our stuff

#new database. Make a copy of initial to prevent serious damage
db_new = sqlite3.connect("your_db_new.sqlite")
for entry in all_entries:
    entry = str(entry[0].strip())#cursor returns tuple
    #since it is time not a date, get milliseconds of the epoch
    date_object = datetime.strptime("Jan 1 1970 " + entry, '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
    new_time = unix_time_millis(date_object)
    #print(entry + " to " + str(new_time))

    cursor_update = db_new.cursor()#new cursor
    try:
        #updating
        cursor_update.execute("UPDATE fancy_table SET time = '" + str(new_time) + "' WHERE arr_time = '" + entry + "'")
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)

db_new.commit()#needs to be commited to take affect
print("done")
```